# Android: Cannot send audio file from raw folder via text or other app

Tags: android, audio, android-intent

I am making a soundboard application and I have an AlertDialog that pops up asking whether the user wants to send a particular audio file from the raw folder to a friend via any app (text, gmail, etc), but when I try to do this, I get "cannot attach file"

Here is my code:

```
            CharSequence choices[] = new CharSequence[] {"Send to friend", "Set as notification sound"};

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
            builder.setTitle("Options");
            builder.setItems(choices, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch(which){
                        case 0:
                            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getContext().getPackageName() + "/" + myAudio[position]));
                            share.setType("audio/*");
                            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share"));
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
            builder.show();
```

myAudio is an array containing the media in the raw folder as such,

```
myAudio = new int[]{ R.raw.audioone, R.raw.audiotwo, R.raw.audiothree};
```

Can anyone spot the issue here? Thanks for any help!

Edit: Here is what I try when told to save to storage first. It still doesn't work :(

```
            CharSequence choices[] = new CharSequence[] {"Send to friend", "Set as notification sound"};

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
            builder.setTitle("Options");
            builder.setItems(choices, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch(which){
                        case 0:
                            /*
                            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getContext().getPackageName() + "/R.raw.hkwheresthelambsauce"));
                            share.setType("audio/*");
                            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share")); */
                            InputStream inputStream;
                            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;
                            try {
                                inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(myAudio[position]);
                                fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                                        new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "sound.mp3"));

                                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                                int length;
                                while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                                    fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
                                }

                                inputStream.close();
                                fileOutputStream.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                                    Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/sound.mp3" ));
                            intent.setType("audio/*");
                            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share sound"));
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
            builder.show();
```

Comment: Those apps cannot load data from your apps resources as you have seen now.

Comment: So I cannot send audio from my raw folder?

Comment: you need to save it to external storage first.

Comment: You could use a dedicated file provider.

Comment: Can you look at my edit? I tried saving to external storage, but it still doesn't work

Comment: Ok, it turns out the test device I was using didn't have external storage. Is there a way to save to internal storage?

Comment: `getExternalStorageDirectory()`. All devices have this external storage.

Comment: `catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }`. Place a Toast() in that catch block to inform the user. And if there is a catch then do not continue with that intent.

Comment: Awesome. Exactly what I needed. Thank you.